# How can I store a bunch of exceptions and return then as the response of an web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to import a bunch of data from an Excel to a DB in my Web API, this data is being validate using [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet#validator-interceptors), the problem is, every time I hit a line with bad information from the Excel table my code stops running and the API returns the exception.

I wish I could store all these exceptions, keep my code running until the end of the Excel table, and then after that return all the exceptions as my API response. I also think it would be a good idea to return in which line of the table the exception occurred.

My code is running inside a for each statement so for storing the line in which errors occurred I can simply start a counter inside of it.

As for keeping my code running I can run it inside of a Try-Catch (or would there be a better way?), but inside of it how can I store all the exceptions together to then return them later?

Comment: In order for us to help you. We need a full sample of the code. We also need to see what you have already tried in order to achieve what you need. And a thorough explanation of why your code is not working along with any errors you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most .NET parts that can return multiple exceptions use `AggregateException` to achieve that. A generic template for that would be:

```cs
var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

foreach (var w in work)
{
    try
    {
        DoWork(w);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        exceptions.Add(e);
    }
}

if (exceptions.Any())
{
    throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
}
```

Here's [the docs for `AggregateException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=netframework-4.8#constructors).

Comment: In this case how could I indicate in which row each exception occurred?

Comment: @RogerioSchmitt You probably want a custom exception that would take an `Exception` and an `int` in its constructor. Then you'd just wrap it before adding it to a list.

Comment: Ended up solving this part by contacting a new exception with my line counter and then adding it to my exceptions list: new Exception($"Error at line {counter}: {e.ToString()}")

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is, every time I hit a line with bad information from the excel table my code stops running and the API returns the exception.

Going on with a process after an exception has never been a good idea. At best the thing you are working with is now in a invalid state and will throw more exceptions "InvalidState" every further access attempt. At worst, it is utterly broken and will cause utterly unpredictbale behavior because it asumes you would not do something so bad. Such behavior can go all the way into your process being kicked out by windows, due to Memory Access Violations.

There is [basic classification](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) I use for Exceptions. While this exception is at worst a Exogenous Exception for your code, it should be considered a fatal one for the parser and this Documet. Going on after it, is not going to add any value. At best, it adds more useless error messages wich hide the real error.

90% of the times you get a compiler error, you get a message because the Syntax is wrong. And often it is so wrong, the Source Code parser can not make heads or tails of what it is seeing anymore. It stop being able to tell you *where the issue even is*.

You should expose/log each exception, stop the parsing after the first one and have the user deal with the issue (wich is clearly outside your job).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an extra column Status in your excel table , for example you can adapt your logic and store in the excel table which stores into DB.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Customer Cust = new Customer();
        List<Customer> Customers = Cust.GetCustomers();

        foreach(Customer c in Customers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string  Status { get; set; }
    List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>();

    public  List<Customer> GetCustomers()
    { 
        //Your Foreach Logic will be replaced
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                Customers.Add(new Customer { Id = i, Name = "Name" + i, Status = "Success Message" });
            }
            else
            {
                Customers.Add(new Customer { Id = i, Name = "Name" + i, Status = "Error Message" });

            }


        }

        return Customers;
    }
}
```